# Inter-process communication between Python and Scala programs

Tags: python, scala, interprocess

I have a website that is backed by CherryPy web framework and a scala program that runs on a same machine and contains an actor system inside. OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

What I want is this: once user fills out and submits a form I send the data from CherryPy backend to scala program as a JSON string. How can this be done? What should I use in my python and scala programs to implement this functionality?

Comment: It depends on how your scala program communicates with the outside world. Does it read from a socket or something? then your Python program can indeed write to that socket whenever it has data.

Comment: @Ashalynd It does not yet but looks like this is the way to go about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are on a *nix system, you may want to look into [Unix domain sockets](http://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html) (that link contains a very clear example use).

You can use the python [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) module to easily create a Unix socket using:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I now more or less understand what I should do. I'll use your link to send data on python side and will find a way to listen to required socket on scala's end.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using raw sockets, you could consider a message broker like RabbitMQ. It supports both Scala and Python.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

On the Scala side, Akka has an AMQP module which abstracts AMQP Connection, Producer and Consumer as Actors.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/amqp.html